# Android: Problems with adjusting view size in an ImageButton

Tags: android, xml, android-imagebutton

I'm trying something that should be simple, an imageButton and some text that says something about it. My problem is, the view of the imageButton is bigger than the image itself. I'm certain that the actual image is not like this (I've tried with several images and the result is the same). By searching online, the solution I've found is to insert the attribute "adjustViewBounds". That seemed reasonable but it didn't work. Here I leave my code and an image of how the result looks.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|top">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:scaleX="0.2"
        android:scaleY="0.2"
        android:src="@drawable/icon1"
        android:padding="0dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DEFAULT!"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8qPN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using `scaleX` and `scaleY` to adjust the size. The button changes it's visible size, but the rest of the layout acts as if it were the original full scale.

I'd suggest using a different method of defining the size, for example:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon1"
        android:padding="0dp"/>
```