# Android scaled ImageView has empty space surrounding it even without padding and scale fitting

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I've seen a number of questions about this, but their suggested solutions have *not* worked for me, so I am asking a new question.

I have a layout like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/character_detail_background"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seriesDetailThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleX="0.6"
        android:scaleY="0.6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/error_placeholder"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This renders a layout like below, with a large empty space on all sides of the image. **How can I get rid of this empty space?**

Based on other questions I've seen on SO, they all recommend using `padding`, `adjustViewBounds` or `scaleXY`. I've used all three as you can see from the XML, however it **has no effect**.

[image]

Comment: With android:scaleX="0.6"  android:scaleY="0.6" you just decrease original view size, you can remove it. Check you error_placeholder image may be it has transparent borders.

Comment: @garmax1 Yes, it does have transparent borders but they are very thin (not nearly as large as shown in the ImageView above). I purposely added the scale because I wanted the image to be a little smaller than the original one that I have.

Comment: This may help from a similar recent question http://stackoverflow.com/a/43105856/5251523

Comment: @LewisMcGeary Thanks, but I was hoping to avoid fixed sizes. I think I'll try Glide or Picasso to do this instead, see if that works and add an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

By default Android will allow you to scale the image down but not up past the image's original size.

You could use glide to scale your image up: [Glide](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling)

```
 Glide  
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.override(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
.into(imageViewResize);
```